# Reputation inconsistent across flair themes

Tags: support, reputation

I've just looked at the falir page - https://serverfault.com/users/flair - and found the numbers there to be inconsistent across the different theme choices.

Whilst I understand that the image generation takes time and so the reputation might not be 100% upto date, I'd expected them to be consistent.

[image]

Comment: Did you try clearing your local cached files and reloading the page?

Comment: @Chris S: Yes.  Just retried and I'm still getting the same.
However, going to http://serverfault.com/users/flair/26468 gives the correct number whilst http://serverfault.com/users/flair/26468.png doesn't.  Maybe this is caching somewhere, either my corporate network or our ISP. Hmm..

Comment: it's probably just the SE caching on their end then. It'll update in a few hours or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image flair is heavily cached on our end; it is normal for there to be 24 to 48 hours of lag between the rep value changing and the image being updated.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just expecting the different themes to be cached at the same time and thus be in sync.